# Using semi_join to find similarities but returns none mistakenly

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, semi-join

I am trying to find the similar genes between two columns that I can later work with just the similar genes. Below is my code:

```
top100_1Beta <- data.frame(grp1_Beta$my_data.SYMBOL[1:100])
top100_2Beta<- data.frame(grp2_Beta$my_data.SYMBOL[1:100])
common100_Beta <- semi_join(top100_1Beta,top100_2Beta)`
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

> Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables

This is wrong since when I open `top100_1Beta` and `top100_2Beta` I can see at least the first few list the exact same genes: ATP2A1, SLMAP, MEOX2,...

I am confused on why then it's returning that no commonalities.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: in the `dplyr` parlance, a "variable" is essentially a column, not a single value within a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need any form of `*_join` here; instead it seems you're looking for `intersect`

```
intersect(grp1_Beta$my_data.SYMBOL[1:100], grp2_Beta$my_data.SYMBOL[1:100])
```

This returns a `vector` of common entries amongst the first 100 entries of `grp1_Beta$my_data.SYMBOL` and `grp1_Beta$my_data.SYMBOL`.

Answer (score 2):

Without a full working example, I'm guessing that your top100_1Beta and top100_2Beta dataframes do not have the same column names.  They are probably `grp1_Beta.my_data.SYMBOL.1.100.` and `grp2_Beta.my_data.SYMBOL.1.100.`.  This means the semi_join function doesn't know where to match the dataframes up. Renaming the columns should fix the issue.